# Check if a python script is running properly and if it isn't re-run it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script which is really buggy and every couple of hours it stops due to an error. I don't code in Python but I know the basics so I would like to know how can I make a script that check another script for errors and if it's true just re-run it?
Sorry for not giving any examples but I think you get the idea and because I'm not good at Python doing this is easier than trying to understand the script and edit it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And where's the script contents? Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is what tools like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) and similar are for. Well, not really, the script should be fixed, but a process controller can at least do the monitoring and restarting.

Comment: The contents are irrelevant, I'm asking for a way to check if a script stopped no matter what the error is

Answer (score 2):

By far the simplest way is to just wait for it to exit and always restart it when it crashes; the following `bash` loop will do nothing while the program is running, and will restart it as soon as it exits:

```bash
while true
do
    python buggy_script.py arguments
    echo oops, restarting...
done
```

And that's it. It'll run forever, until you kill the bash script that's running it.

PS. Of course this assumes you are on OS X or Linux; if you're on Windows, use an equivalent batch or PowerShell script.

Comment: I'd suggest using PowerShell instead of batch; batch looks horrible to me.

Comment: Sure, PowerShell then. Anything with a loop will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a daemon for the script.

Basically keep the main functionality in a loop that will run forever.

`import logging
import time
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        //log errors
        logging.basicConfig(filename='log_file.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
        // use try except to handle exceptions
        try:
            // your code statements and function calls
        except Exception as e:
            // log the error for debugging
            logging.error(str(e))
        // sleep the program if you want it to for desired amount of time.
        time.sleep(delay)`

The level of logging I set is debug. You can set it to any other of your own choice.

References :

Logging Docs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Handling exceptions - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions